# Precedence order for a complex expression

Tags: c, operators

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num, var;
    num = (var=15, var+=35);
    printf("%d",num);
}
```

here num evaluates as 50.
 I want to verify
My reasoning :- inside (..),
 we first read from left to right to see all operands available, 
make an order of preference, 
then evaluate += = , (in order).
 Finally we have var=50, which gets assigned to num. Am I correct?

Comment: Is your only question regarding the order in which the contents of the `(...)` are executed?

Comment: @ryyker ....yes

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
(var=15, var+=35)
```

uses the *comma operator*, which evaluates each subexpression from left to right.  The comma introduces a *sequence point*, so the side effects of each subexpression are applied before the next subexpression is evaluated. The type and result of the expression is the type and result of the rightmost subexpression.  It's equivalent to writing:

```
var = 15;
var += 35;
num = var;
```

Please note that the comma operator used above is *not* the same as the comma that separates arguments in a function call - function arguments are *not* guaranteed to be evaluated from left to right, and side effects are only guaranteed to be applied before the function is called, not after each argument is evaluated.